# android service - opening socket throws null exception

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-service, socketexception

I'm trying to create remote service that will take care for all client-server communication for few different apps.
The main idea is starting the service from main activity and open a communication socket to a server.
after that, the socket will be used by other apps - that's why i want to use remote service for it...

now i have an issue with the socket connection, it throws null exception on my device.
it works fine on AVD using older android version.

here's some parts of my code:

my main activity:

```
final ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            myRemoteService = ConnectionInterface.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            myRemoteService = null;
        }
    };

    final Thread t = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            bindService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConnectionRemoteService.class),conn,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            while(true){}
        }

   };
```

later on i start the Thread t with t.start();

my ConnectionRemoteService:

```
package com.mainlauncher;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectionRemoteService extends Service {

private static final int SERVERPORT = 7777;
private static final String SERVERADDRESS = "192.168.1.106";

private String deviceID;
private Socket socket;
private DataInputStream in;
private DataOutputStream out;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    deviceID = wm.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service On.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    open();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Off.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    close();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myRemoteServiceStub;
}   

private ConnectionInterface.Stub myRemoteServiceStub = new ConnectionInterface.Stub() {

};

void open(){
    try{
        socket = new Socket(SERVERADDRESS,SERVERPORT);
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF(deviceID);
    }
    catch(Exception  e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

void close(){
    try {
        if(in!=null)
            in.close();
        if(out!=null)
            out.close();
        if(socket!=null)
            socket.close();
    } 
    catch(Exception  e){
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    socket=null;

}

}
```

Main Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mainlauncher"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity android:name=".MainLauncherWindow" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".ConnectionRemoteService"
        android:process=":remote"/>
</application>
```

here's DDMS log on "debug" mode as requested:

> 11-06 12:13:45.130: D/InputDispatcher(392): notifyMotion - eventTime=4210399491000, deviceId=6, source=0x1002, policyFlags=0x0, action=0x0, flags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, xPrecision=1.529167, yPrecision=1.383594, downTime=4210399491000
>   11-06 12:13:45.130: D/InputDispatcher(392):   Pointer 0: id=0, toolType=1, x=66.049042, y=492.196503, pressure=0.233333, size=0.250980, touchMajor=44.054604, touchMinor=44.054604, toolMajor=4.818472, toolMinor=4.818472, orientation=0.000000
>   11-06 12:13:45.130: D/InputDispatcher(392): Dispatch MotionEvent [action=0] ToCurrentInputTarget: 40f9a6a8 com.mainlauncher/com.mainlauncher.MainLauncherWindow (server)
>   11-06 12:13:45.150: D/PowerManagerService(392): setPowerState: mPowerState=0x3, newState=0x3, noChangeLights=false, reason=3, force=false, mProximitySensorActive=false, mBootCompleted=true, mUseSoftwareAutoBrightness=true (repeat:1)
>   11-06 12:13:45.160: D/PowerManagerService(392): setPowerState: mPowerState=0x3, newState=0x3, noChangeLights=false, reason=2, force=false, mProximitySensorActive=false, mBootCompleted=true, mUseSoftwareAutoBrightness=true
>   11-06 12:13:45.160: I/PowerManagerService-JNI(392): [Stability] PowerManagerService_userActivity JNI pass power key event to PowerManagerService userActivity()
>   11-06 12:13:45.160: D/PowerManagerService(392): setTimeoutLocked: now=4210399, timeoutOverride=-1, nextState=0x3, when=4216399 (mKeylightDelay=6000, mDimDelay=2147469000, mScreenOffDelay=7000)
>   11-06 12:13:45.190: D/InputDispatcher(392): notifyMotion - eventTime=4210464940000, deviceId=6, source=0x1002, policyFlags=0x0, action=0x1, flags=0x0, metaState=0x0, buttonState=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, xPrecision=1.529167, yPrecision=1.383594, downTime=4210399491000
>   11-06 12:13:45.190: D/InputDispatcher(392):   Pointer 0: id=0, toolType=1, x=65.395096, y=492.919250, pressure=0.233333, size=0.219608, touchMajor=38.547779, touchMinor=38.547779, toolMajor=4.818472, toolMinor=4.818472, orientation=0.000000
>   11-06 12:13:45.190: D/InputDispatcher(392): Dispatch MotionEvent [action=1] ToCurrentInputTarget: 40f9a6a8 com.mainlauncher/com.mainlauncher.MainLauncherWindow (server)
>   11-06 12:13:45.220: D/dalvikvm(153): Before fork
>   11-06 12:13:45.230: D/dalvikvm(20210): Fork pid: 0
>   11-06 12:13:45.230: D/dalvikvm(20210): Late-enabling CheckJNI
>   11-06 12:13:45.230: D/dalvikvm(153): Fork pid: 20210
>   11-06 12:13:45.240: D/Performance(392): AutoProf Starting process { Process=com.mainlauncher:remote, ActivityName=com.mainlauncher/.ConnectionRemoteService}, pid=20210
>   11-06 12:13:45.240: I/ActivityManager(392): Start proc com.mainlauncher:remote for service com.mainlauncher/.ConnectionRemoteService: pid=20210 uid=10080 gids={3003}
>   11-06 12:13:45.300: D/ConnSrv_Debug(392): get mDefaultProxy null by 20210/10080
>   11-06 12:13:45.300: D/WifiStateMachine(392): syncRequestConnectionInfo mWifiInfo=SSID: linksys, BSSID: 00:14:bf:e6:13:8f, MAC: 18:87:96:88:cd:68, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, RSSI: -83, Link speed: 36, Frequency: 2462, Net ID: 1, Explicit connect: false
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: D/AndroidRuntime(20210): Shutting down VM
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: W/dalvikvm(20210): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a6b228)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/EmbeddedLogger(392): App crashed! Process: com.mainlauncher:remote
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/EmbeddedLogger(392): App crashed! Package: com.mainlauncher v1 (1.0)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.mainlauncher.ConnectionRemoteService: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2593)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:139)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5025)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at com.mainlauncher.ConnectionRemoteService.open(ConnectionRemoteService.java:60)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at com.mainlauncher.ConnectionRemoteService.onCreate(ConnectionRemoteService.java:33)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2571)
>   11-06 12:13:45.320: E/AndroidRuntime(20210):    ... 10 more
>   11-06 12:13:45.330: E/EmbeddedLogger(392): Application Label: Launcher

I get the exception on this line:

```
socket = new Socket(SERVERADDRESS,SERVERPORT);
```

I know few things that can make that exception:
1. I use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in my main manifest.
2. The Service run under separated thread, not on the main activity thread.
3. There's no firewall etc...
4. I checked connection with the server already (all worked fine without the service).
5. I'm using android:process=":remote" in my manifest too.

any ideas why that exception occurs?
how can i debug it to get more details?

it worked find on AVD using OS 2.3, so i think it's something with the main activity thread exception, but i can't find out why.

thanks,
Lioz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `open()` from `onCreate()`. `onCreate()` is called on the main thread. You shouldn't do network I/O on the main thread. You've got the separate thread thing in the wrong place. In your activity you're starting a separate thread that calls `bindService()` and then loops forever (infinite loop chewing up CPU cycles, not a good thing). You don't need to call `bindService()` from inside a separate thread because `bindService()` is asynchronous. It only **initiates** the binding, it doesn't actually wait for the binding to complete. This can be done on the main thread.

Where you need to start a thread is inside your service. When your service gets created, you should start a separate thread in `onCreate()` and that separate thread needs to do the network I/O (ie: open socket, read, write, etc.).

Also, you can make debugging easier by removing `android:process=":remote"` from the manifest. This will allow you to set breakpoints easier in the service methods.

Comment: so that's the point, i was sure it's something with the main activity thread issue... thanks (again) David. the infinite loop was only for testing (make sure the the thread keep running). thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to put the Internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml?
Connecting to a server (even its a "local" running server) needs internet permissions i think.

Comment: yup, it was the 1st thing i wrote in my question, now I've noticed that it wasn't surrounded with code so it was hidden. edited and fixed... any other ideas?

Comment: can you post your AndroidManifest.xml and the Exception please? Maybe it's the WiFiManager that crashes? To see the complete Exception, open the Debug console in Eclipse or start the DDMS tool ;)

Comment: added the Manifest file, the exception occurs on the open socket command, i checked it few times and only this line makes the crash... I'll update the complete crash soon.